# How to make Bootstrap Navbar "non-responsive"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap to design a webpage. In that I am using Bootstrap Navbars however I don't want them to be responsive. I tried making changes to **variables.less** file, adding `.container { width: @container-desktop !important; }` to my css file but none has worked so far. My code is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar-custom navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div style="width: 95%; margin:0 auto;" >
    <div class="container-fluid">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://someURL/"><img  src="images/someImage"></a>
       <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav myCustomClass1">
              <li><span class="name">Welcome Mr Blah, Blah </span></li>
              <li><span class="logo1">someStuff</span></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top test">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>

    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <div style="width: 95%; margin:0 auto;" >
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav align-nav-items">
        <li ng-class="{active: someThing}"><a href="#/somePage">aaa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/otherPage">bbb</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: someThing}"><a href="#/anotherPage">ccc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/otherURL">ddd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/anotherURL">eee</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/someURL">fff</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/someOtherURL">ggg</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav myCustomClass2">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>xxx</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Please forgive the slightly faulty indentation. The custom css classes are:

```
.myCustomClass1
{
  float: right;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:1.5%;

}

.myCustomClass2 {
  float: right;
 margin:0 auto;


}
```

Is there any way by which I can make such code non-responsive? What I essentially want it to do is instead of responsively changing the design, I want it to get clipped good old fashioned way and make the page horizontally scrollable.

Comment: Define a fixed width in pixels rather than in percentage.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal where exactly?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to have only the navbar non-resposive, while keeping all other elements responsive right?

Comment: do you want the whole website to be non-responsive? [try this](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/) then

Comment: @AvAvt, on second thought, I wont mind trying a completely nonResponsive layout

Comment: @ashhem You should know where exactly you want to be non-responsive. Try my answer.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I did and sadly its not working. It only reduces or increases the overall width but does not kill the responsiveness..

Comment: @ashhem to which navbar you're trying?

Comment: @ashhem you can try the non-responsive bootstrap layout I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want this in the markup:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
</button>
```

also change

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
```

to

```
<div id="myNavbar">
```

Change the css for `.nav > li` and `.nav > li > a`. Both should be `display: block` by default (Bootstrap). Change them to `display: inline`. Style the rest according to your needs.

**Edit based on user's JSFiddle:**

Is this how you want it? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dreamster/v7hdbtje/1/)

I've added:

```
.navbar-inverse {
  /* other styles */
  height: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.align-nav-items {
  min-width: 390px;
}
.nav > li, .nav > li > a {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: will test and let you know!

Comment: Not working sir! While the Hamburger menu does not come anymore, Instead of giving me a scroll bar, I can only see the aaa tab and xxx tab with all others gone..

Comment: There is an improvement. Now what this is doing is, it is creating a second line in navbar itself and cramping it up.

Comment: maybe there isn't enough space for the additional nav items. Can you kindly post a JSFiddle?

Comment: let me try. I am not to sure I will be able include so many dependencies.. Just gimme some time..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v7hdbtje/
Could recreate it 90% 
I am missing adding someclass in CSS as a result of which, the tabs in the navbar are aligned vertically one below the other instead of one after other. Do check if you can work with it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97597/discussion-between-ashhem-and-dreamster).

Answer (score 0):

To make navbar non-responsive and all other keep responsive just do the following:

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top.test{
   min-width: 1200px;/*define as you require*/
}
```

Comment: Tried it, What this is doing is it is instead of giving me the scroll bar, it cramping up all the tabs just above my navbar.